# Is `useLayoutEffect` preferable to `useEffect` when reading layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

One difference about `useLayoutEffect` vs `useEffect` is that `useLayoutEffect` will be fired synchronously after DOM mutation and before the browser paint phase. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513872/react-hooks-what-is-the-difference-between-usemutationeffect-and-uselayoutef))

However, I've came across some articles and they all seem to recommend to use `useLayoutEffect` for reading layout.

[React docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)

> The signature is identical to useEffect, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. *Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render*. Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

[Kent C.Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect):

> useLayoutEffect: If you need to mutate the DOM and/or *do need to perform measurements*.

[Ohans Emmanuel:](https://blog.logrocket.com/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect/)

> Where possible, choose the useEffect Hook for cases where you want to be unobtrusive in the dealings of the browser paint process. In the real world, this is usually most times! *Well, except when you’re reading layout from the DOM* or doing something DOM-related that needs to be painted ASAP.

As I understand, by the time the `useEffect` is fired, the browser has already passed the layout and paint phase, so reading layout in `useEffect` should be totally okay.

So my question: Is `useLayoutEffect` preferable to `useEffect` when reading layout and if yes, why? Taken that I just only read the layout and don't perform any additional state changes in the effect.

Comment: For **reading** - its not preferable, for **attaching** it does, same as mentioned in the docs

Answer (score 5):

The following diagram always helps me to visualize the flow of hooks and also will let you clarify regarding why `useLayoutEffect` is recommended over `useEffect` for DOM based operations (where you're targetting stuff that you can update before current browser paint)

[image]

Link to the diagram - https://github.com/donavon/hook-flow

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this diagram.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have DOM manipulating code in the hook and only reading layout useEffect will do just fine.

If you do have DOM manipulating code in the useEffect and see screen flickering move this code to useLayoutEffect.

It goes like this:

1. Render
2. useLayoutEffect (synchronously after all DOM mutations)
3. Paint
4. useEffect

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you as a developer consider 'preferable'. In the context of your question `useLayoutEffect` guarantees that you will see layout before mutation, `useEffect` shows you what happens after.

Comment: By "preferable", I mean does it have any advantages (between the `useLayoutEffect` vs `useEffect`) when it comes to just reading the layout?

Comment: @dongnhan I would say ‘useEffect’ is safer to use in your case, since it doesn’t block rendering. And you will be confident that you are getting most recent DOM data.

Comment: I think you have a point about render blocking. About getting the most recent DOM data, in the layout phase, the browser has already calculated all the spaces correctly and then later in the paint phase, the browser just fills the pixels, so I don't think getting most recent DOM data is correct. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering#the_pixel_pipeline

Comment: @dongnhan I think you are mistaking browser lifecycle and React lifecycle. All React stuff is contained inside javascript phase, size calculations happen after React pushed changes into the dom. And ‘useLayoutEffect’ happens in between, preventing react from releasing DOM updates. ‘useEffect’ happens after all DOM updates finish.

Comment: @dongnhan ‘ Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.’ from your quotes.

Comment: "size calculations happen after React pushed changes into the dom". If this is true, then you could not read the layout in `useLayoutEffect` (since the DOM updates has not been released)? But in fact we could totally read the layout in `useLayoutEffect`. How would you explain that, I would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @dongnhan With ‘ useLayoutEffect’ you read previous state of DOM. With ‘useEffect’ you read next state of DOM after update. 

Let’s say you have stateful component which toggles green/red color of div based on ‘isValid’ boolean in the state. Initial value is false/red. Then you trigger the action to change to true/green. ‘useLayoutEffect’ will report red, ‘useEffect’ green.

Comment: I created a demo and seems like it's not working as you said. https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-breeze-c107p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In your example you are inspecting state, but we are talking about DOM. So you should traverse the DOM Document.getElementsByClassName(‘App’)

Comment: Thanks for pointing. Could you help modify the demo to show your point please?

Comment: Hi, I think I got your point. By "getting the most recent DOM data", `useEffect` will be better in case you *perform some mutations in `useLayoutEffect`* (since the changes in `useLayoutEffect` will be flushed and by the time `useEffect` is called, everything has been set and painted). I think I need to clarify my original question a bit, I just want to emphasize on "reading the layout" in `useEffect` vs `useLayoutEffect` and taken that I don't perform any mutations.

Comment: @DimaVishnyakov Reading DOM also gets 2 reds/2 greens. https://codesandbox.io/s/red-shadow-5d475